# Angular 5, ionic 3 data is not getting binded on success of Http post request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, data-binding, fabricjs, angular5

I am trying to implement http post requests on mouse up event, It is working fine in browser, the data which is received is **not getting binded to the variable** declared on success of Http post request **when i test it on my mobile**. I have to tap somewhere on the screen for the data to get binded to the variable and show the result.

My code for mouse up event:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.canvas.on('mouse:up', (o) => {
   if (this.isAutoDraw) {
    var image = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    this.autoDrawRequest(image)
   }
 });
}
```

Code for HTTP post request

```
imgList;
autoDrawRequest(img){
  this._Manager.autoDrawServer(img).subscribe(
   data => {
    console.log(data);
    imgList = data;
   },
   error => {
    this.isError = true;
    this._Util.showToast("Error");
 });
}
```

HTML code

```
<div *ngFor="let img of imgList>
  {{img}}
</div>
```

Data consoled on success is getting printed, but the value I am trying to show in html is not getting displayed until I tap somewhere on the screen.

I am working on auto draw.. so on each stroke i want to give some suggestions..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are calling your `autoDrawRequest` function on the mouse up event. It will update when you tap on the screen. If you want to do this on load just move it outside your canvas event.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  if (this.isAutoDraw) {
    var image = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    this.autoDrawRequest(image)
  }
}
```

You can learn more about the ionic lifecycle events in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: I am working on auto draw.. so on each stroke i want to give some suggestions.. that is why i have used on mouse up

Comment: You could call it once outside the event and then bind it so it will be called on mouse up.

Comment: I am confused with the "it" you used. Could you please explain it briefly
thanks

Comment: i want to call autoDrawRequest on each stroke.. so can give the suggestion according to it... that is why i kept the function call on mouse up